# How can I properly convert a sum of spherical waves to a definite integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation

I have an equation:

$\cos \left(\sqrt{\left(x_f-x_i\right){}^2+\left(y_f+y_i\right){}^2}\right)$

where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are constants, that gives the following graph as a function of $x_f$ and $y_f$:

[image]

where, at some constant position $x_f$ the 2D graph of the equation as a function of $y_f$ gives the $z$ height like the following:

[image]

I am trying to find a way to write an integral (unsolved) that represents the height $z$ as a function of the location $(x_f, y_f)$ and the initial values $(x_i, y_i)$ where the $y_i$ value goes from $0$ to $l$.

$\sum _{i=1}^n \text{Cos}\left[\sqrt{\left(x_f-x_i\right){}^2+\left(y_f-\text{$\Delta $y} i\right){}^2}\right.$ where the limit of n goes to infinity.

And for the integral, I have:

$\int _0^l\cos \left(\sqrt{\left(x_f-x_i\right){}^2+\left(y_f-dy\right){}^2}\right)$$dy$,

but I don't think this is the correct way to write it. Does anybody know how it is that I can write this integral in terms of what I am trying to accomplish? Thanks.

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/529760/2451

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish is confusing. You say you want an integral that "represents the height $z$". What do you mean by "represents"? If you mean that result of the integral is supposed to be the height, then using that height as the integrand is not going to do this. Besides, why would you want to express the height as an integral, when you already have it as a simpler formula? Also, the last integral should have $(y_f - y)^2$, not $(y_f -dy)^2$.